# Android: Suggest open source app to learn MySQL connectivity

Tags: android

Please Suggest open source app to learn MySQL connectivity.

I'm creating a app which have login, register new user, browse different product, buy product..

All things is dynamic and comes from the MySQL database. I want reference app which help me achieve this in easy and sufficient way.

Please suggest an open source project or reference to complete the task.

Comment: you should not access mysql db directly from your phone first create a webservice(for example with php) and then get or set data within webservice

Comment: Yes, I've learn the basics functionalists using php web service and parsing json. But, i need a reference to learn complex web service and how to make secure connection.

Comment: you can have a good practice [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) and also Notpad is good example in Android API.

Comment: Thanks but my database is MySQL. Notepad example also uses SQLite so not of my use..

Answer (score 0):

you could use this book it have many examples and complete covereage of webservice :

[Web Database Applications with PHP & MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596000413)

[How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)

[Create a Basic Web Service Using PHP, MySQL, XML, and JSON](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest me an open source project or practical example so that i can learn fast.

Comment: I'm done with the basics. I've creted the Login function but it's not the best way coz i learnt from he begginers tutorials and have some problems. I also want to lean the data handling from multiple table and show them in listview. Need to handle money transaction from app. So, i want a reference not fro beginners